# Attaching a block to a view create with the User type

Tags: views

I have created a view using the User type.  The view has 2 entity relationships to a location content type and a manager content type.  With this I have setup contextual information relevant to the user's location and manager.

Now I need to add a generic video into the view as well.  I have created a video content type and have it displayed using mediaelement.

My question is how do I add this content to my user type view?  I am not sure if I am missing a really obvious way of doing this :p

I initially thought that I would be able to create a separate block view for the video then attach it to the original user view - but no luck there.

Comment: why dont you create a different view with the video and add it the region where the user block is.

Comment: Ideally I wanted to include the fields into the view so I could order them on the page so the text flows around the video.

Comment: is the video related to the user in any manner?

Comment: it is a generic video that will appear to all users.  I am just wondering if I could create a taxonomy relationship to it as the video only appears in this one place...

Comment: you can add a global text and then insert the video in that.

Comment: It's looking like that might have to be the option, was hoping not to have to add in the code to display the video - makes updating the video a bit harder for future maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found around this is that in the the fields I added a Global View.  Now the video is treated just as a field.